# is.numeric gives inconsistent TRUE/FALSE on imported .csv file

Tags: r, import, numeric

I import the .csv file into R, then use filter in dplyr to get the section I need
I need to use the scores for cor and rcorr, so these variables must be numeric.

```
> dummysubj <- read.csv("~/Documents/Ragstats/dummysubj.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>   View(dummysubj)
#need to select the subj from larger file
> Acc101<-filter(dummysubj,Subj=="Acc101")
> View (Acc101)
#need to get rid of 2 blank variables full of na
> Acc101vcut<-Acc101[-c(-5,-6)]
> print(Acc101vcut)
    Subj Studno A1 A2 Ymrk Fmrk
1 Acc101 123456 50 34   50   50
2 Acc101 123457 50 74   50   50
3 Acc101 123458 63 63   63   63
4 Acc101 123459 50 50   50   50
5 Acc101 123460 59 49   59   59
6 Acc101 123461 NA 82   41   41
7 Acc101 123462 NA NA <NA> <NA>
8 Acc101 123463 74 NA   74   74
9 Acc101 123464 75 76   75   75
> is.numeric(Acc101vcut$A1)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(Acc101vcut$Fmrk)
[1] FALSE
```

Why is A1 showing up as numeric while Fmrk is still a factor ? They both have na in the column but I used stringsAsFactors = FALSE in the import

Comment: use `str(Acc101vcut)` for a quick look at the class of the variables It could be that there is a character, for example a comma, somewhere in the offending column.

Comment: ... it is worth looking at `dummysubj` as soon as the data is read in. Prepare the data for analysis at this stage, making sure all the columns are the expected class. imo it is better to find why they are not, rather than a forced conversion to numeric as this can cause loss of data

Comment: As op mentions it sees to be a problem at import. Check the structure of your data before filtering and look for any irregularities in the full dataset. There is likely a non-numeric entry in the `Fmrk` column of the full dataset.